# Reduce the length of the title

Tags: 7

Am using custom breadcrumb  module for breadcrumbs in drupal .Is there any option to reduce the length of my active title?

Comment: If there isn't then it would be possible to do it programmatically with hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Altering the breadcrumb contents](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69363/altering-the-breadcrumb-contents)

Comment: actually I ve got a solution but I want to seperate the page title and custom breadcrumb active trail Is that possible